# Magento - Create an attribute to config path

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I have created a personalized attribute for my clients and I would like to be able to call it directly on the editor of my CMS on Magento. I wanted to do like the system variables available on magento and I thought to create one directly on my database in the config path but I do not see how to proceed ... I had also thought of creating a template, by directly calling my attribute, and even though it works I was told it was not the best method. Are there other ways to proceed? thank you in advance, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about "System Configurations".

You can create then using a `system.xml` file, and access then using helpers.

Check these links:

- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html
- https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-system-xml-configuration-in-magento-2/